# need excel files to be opened and maximize and always be opened

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

our computers in our company always turn on and we dont restart them... (if need hibernate them)

some excel  files in network drive shared and we want to open all over the time in some PCs

which of these 3 possibilities possible? **and HOW?**

- is there any way to check that if closed , and then open them?
- is there any way if they are minimized , restored? and user force to 
  put some information to them?
- is there ay way to stick excel files on desktop?

Comment: The first is possible, you would need to write a script that runs every x minutes (using windows task scheduler) check to see if excel is open, from there you can maximize the window and/or open the file. This is a non trivial programming task.

Comment: How can you maximize all of these files all the time? Is there only one of them open on each machine? If you have more than one open on a machine, they can't ALL be fully maximized simultaneously